Need to provide addition steps to pydantic model initialisation method
I am trying to add custom steps to the Pydantic model __init__ method.
Pseudo Sample Code :
class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[List[int]] = None
    c: Optional[int] = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.method()

    def method(self):
        assert self.a is not None, "Value for a is not set"  # As a safety precaution let's say
        self.c = sum(self.b)  # Adds all the values in B and sets the sum to C

When I initialise the method
[In]: x = Model(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4])
[Out]: pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for A
     response -> Model -> 0
     Value for a is not set (type=value_error)

I get this error even thou I have set both a and b in the model. Can someone help me out
The same problem works if the method is called outside the __init__ method, but I want the method to be called upon initialisation and not manually
Pseudo Sample Code :
class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[List[int]] = None
    c: Optional[int] = None

    def method(self):
        assert self.a is not None, "Value for a is not set"  # As a safety precaution let's say
        self.c = sum(self.b)  # Adds all the values in B and sets the sum to C

When I initialise the method
[In]: x = Model(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4])
[Out]: Model(a=1, b=[1, 2 , 3 , 4], c=None)

[In]: x.method()
[Out]: Model(a=1, b=[1, 2 , 3 , 4], c=10)


Note: I'm restricted with the pydantic version '1.10.14'and cannot upgrade it for several reasons.


Update Jun 18th
After getting a few answers and help, I went with the validator method. But I went through few hiccups, which I have explained below
Updated pseudo code :
from pydantic import validator

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[List[int]] = None
    c: Optional[int] = None

    @root_validator(pre=False, allow_reuse=False)
    def method(cls, values, **kwargs):

        assert values["b"] is not None, "Value for b is not set"
        values["c"] = sum(values["b"])

        return values

    def serialise(self):
        ...
        // Creates protobuf message

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, message) -> "Model":
        ...
        // reads the protobuf message and creates the cls
        
        return cls(
            a = message.a
            c = message.c
        )

>>> x = Model(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
    
    Model(a=1 b=[1, 2, 3, 4] c=10)
>>>
>>> x.serialise()

    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>>>
>>> y = Model.desirealise("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    Value for b is not set

In this case, I don't want to run the validator when c is manually set during the model is initiated.
Hence, I set skip_on_failure flag to True for the validator and I have made the below changes to prevent the check from failing.
from pydantic import validator

class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[List[int]] = None
    c: Optional[int] = None

    @root_validator(pre=False, allow_reuse=False)
    def method(cls, values, **kwargs):
        if values["c"] is not None:
            return values

        assert values["b"] is not None, "Value for b is not set"
        values["c"] sum(values["b"])

        return values

    def serialise(self):
        ...
        // Creates protobuf message

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, message) -> "Model":
        ...
        // reads the protobuf message and creates the cls
        
        return cls(
            a = message.a
            c = message.c
        )

>>> x = Model(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
    
    Model(a=1 b=[1, 2, 3, 4] c=10)
>>>
>>> x.serialise()

    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>>>
>>> y = Model.desirealise("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    Model(a=1, b=None, c=10)

This code resolves my issues and works properly with the system, but I want to know if this is a best practice or If any other way is there to do this.

I'm not sure what the goal of using the assert for a is: Pydantic should catch that error regardless as a is defined as just an int and is not Optional. But your b parameter is defined as optional, and you're then trying to call sum on that regardless of whether it's None or not  -- so what is the goal with the assert, and why is b optional if you're always expecting to call sum on it?

Hi @MatsLindh, Due to confidentiality reasons, I can't share the specific use case. However, I've provided a pseudo-code example using a sum operation. In reality, I have a complex logic running to calculate c that depends on a and many other attributes and parameters. My goal is to find a way to call the method automatically upon initialization.
I hope this clarifies the situation.

This answer might prove helpful as well.

I hope my updated question post implementation of the suggested answers, clarifies your previous comment @MatsLindh. Let me if any more clarification needed

Pydantic v2 answer:
If you want to both validate and add logic to your property during initialization, you can use model_validator:
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic import model_validator


class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[List[int]] = None
    c: Optional[int] = None


    @model_validator(mode='after')
    def method(self):
        assert self.a is not None, "Value for a is not set"  # As a safety precausion let say
        self.c = sum(self.b)  # Adds all the value in B and sets the sum to C


print(Model(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
# a=1 b=[1, 2, 3, 4] c=10

But I think it's a better approach to separate responsabilities with @model_validator and @computed_field:
from pydantic import computed_field
from pydantic import model_validator


class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[List[int]] = None

    @model_validator(mode='after')
    def method(self):
        assert self.a is not None, "Value for a is not set"

    @computed_field
    @property
    def c(self) -> int:
        return sum(self.b)

print(Model(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
# a=1 b=[1, 2, 3, 4] c=10

Pydantic v1 (1.10.14) answer:
Since pydantic v1 don't offer computed_field, you can still rely on model/field validations. In this case, the validator decorator:
from pydantic import validator


class Model(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: Optional[List[int]] = None
    c: Optional[int] = None

    @validator("c", always=True)
    def method(cls, v, values, **kwargs):
        assert values["a"] is not None, "Value for a is not set"
        return sum(values["b"])

print(Model(a=1, b=[1, 2, 3, 4]))
# a=1 b=[1, 2, 3, 4] c=10


Pydantic has no modules named model_validator or computed_field in my version.
My pydantic version is '1.10.14'. Is it possible for a different method to get the same result without upgrading the pydantic version? I'm restricted by this version and cannot upgrade it for several reasons.

@AIGAMER added an example with version 1.10.14. Hope that helps ;)

Your suggestion helped me a lot, thank you. But I went through a few hiccups in my flow post-implementation and I have again updated the question, kindly give your thoughts and correct me if I did anything wrong.
